# how to replace files in subfolder with scp?

Tags: bash

Context :

I'm in a limited environment forced to used `SCP` (`rsync` is not available)

Problem :

Using `SCP`, I copy a folder. However it does not replace existing file and I need to do it. How can I do this with `SCP`?

Comment: normally scp overwrites files, you don't need to do anything for that. Are you sure about path?

Comment: scp -r (recursive) for the folder + content. Make sure your rights are ok so it is allowed to overwrite files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had a running process using the folder which locked the files...

my command is (and works fine) :

```
scp -rp "DAILY_TEST_FOLDER" "root@${IPADDRESS}:/home/root/"
```